# Working with NDK in Eclipse

Tags: android, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

I want to use C code in Android application for a set of operations. I have successfully installed Android ADT and downloaded then extracted NDK. I have already installed Additional new Softwares from  `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`. When I now want to add NDK path in eclipse it does not list in the  **Windows->Preferences->Android** location.

I am using Eclipse juno.

[image]

I have searched for it on internet but didn't got much help.
Please point out if I am missing something here or guide through the process

Comment: double check if `Android Native Development Tools` is installed from google repository

Comment: Yes it is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> set path to the NDK        (C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle) [or where you put it!]